# Exportação Crystal Reports CSV Filtrado por Data (C# MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, csv, crystal-reports

Tenho um objeto Crystal Report que está trazendo os registros de uma View de um banco de dados MySQL.
Preciso que estes registros sejam exportados para um arquivo CSV e consegui isso com o seguinte código:

```
private void btnExportarCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string fileName = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";
        fileName = Config.pathFiles + "\\" + fileName;
        Reports.NotaFiscal_CSVReport cr = new Reports.NotaFiscal_CSVReport();

        DiskFileDestinationOptions diskOpts = ExportOptions.CreateDiskFileDestinationOptions();
        diskOpts.DiskFileName = fileName;

        CharacterSeparatedValuesFormatOptions csvFO = ExportOptions.CreateCharacterSeparatedValuesFormatOptions();
        csvFO.ReportSectionsOption = CsvExportSectionsOption.ExportIsolated;
        csvFO.ExportMode = CsvExportMode.Standard;
        csvFO.SeparatorText = ";";
        csvFO.Delimiter = "";

        ExportOptions exportOpts = new ExportOptions();
        exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.CharacterSeparatedValues;
        exportOpts.ExportFormatOptions = csvFO;
        exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
        exportOpts.ExportDestinationOptions = diskOpts;

        cr.Export(exportOpts);

}
```

O problema é que tem um campo desta view que é uma data. E eu preciso que o relatório exporte apenas os registros cuja data esteja num intervalo especificado. Tentei fazer isso de várias formas, com parâmetros, fórmulas... mas sem sucesso.

Alguém sabe a forma correta de se fazer isso? Lembrando que o relatório está vinculado a uma view, o dataset do relatório não está sendo setado no código...

Valeu!